# Target variable is defined by combination of input features

Tags: classification, feature-engineering, predictor, independence, dependent-variable

I am trying to create a classification model which predicts whether or not a customer comes back to make a second transaction (after having made an initial transaction). I have details on date of first purchase and second purchase (wherever a second purchase has happened, doesn't always). I am considering any second transaction within a 90 day window as a customer who repurchases, others outside of that window are not considered a returning customer. My problem is that I intend to use a feature, days since first purchase, as one of my input fields. However, my target is now defined by this feature. This feature now is dominant in it's feature importance, but is purely a result of the way I have defined my target. What is the correct approach to avoid this error here? Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: 1) Why is this an error? // 2) When you don't know if someone will be a return customer, how do you obtain the information on the gap between purchases? (Perhaps this answers the first question.)

Comment: Where is the problem? You run your model today, a given customer is $n$ days from their first purchase, you output a probability. You re-run your model tomorrow, the same customer now is $n+1$ days from their first purchase, you get a different prediction. You are working off different information sets. (It might make more sense to use days since the *last* purchase.)

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa I think you are right. My concern now is maybe just that this one feature is highly correlated with the target, although not entirely the definition of the target. Although I'm realizing now there may be nothing inherently incorrect with that. There is no target leakage happening since I can at any point calculate number of days since last purchase.

Comment: Something that's still not adding up though is that in some cases my model simply can rely on a numeric rule -- if purchase date is more than 90 days ago, then flag as non-returning. Which misrepresents actual predictive power, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your outcome seems to be a deterministic function of a feature. If someone buys again within $90$ days, they are a return customer. If they do not buy again within $90$ days, they are not. There is no statistical or machine learning modeling to do here, just a definition check.

However, I see it as a major issue that you are trying to make a predictive model with information that will not be available until after you have observed the outcome. You do not know the gap between purchases until they make the purchase, at which point, you know if that customer counts as a return customer. You only have that information at a time when statistical modeling is obsolete because of the completely deterministic relationship.

Consider what you will do when someone new makes a purchase. You have no idea when they will make their next purchase until they make that purchase, at which point, you know with certainty if that person was a return customer or not.